# Python using return value of a function as an argument?

Tags: python

Let's say that there was functionA:

```
def functionA():
  return 'foo','bar'
```

and there was functionB:

```
def functionB(first,second):
  print(first)
  print(second)
```

and I wanted to use the output of function A as an argument for function B, like this:

```
functionB(functionA())
```

But that doesn't work because python thinks that functionB expects 2 arguments and function A is only one argument, and it gives me an error. How do I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `functionB(*functionA())`

Comment: @rdas where can I find more information about this? what is it called? thank You in advance

Comment: [Argument packing & unpacking](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

Comment: Or [passing a tuple in *args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794115/passing-a-tuple-in-args) (which links to the extensive [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters))